# SQL query to select rows based on condition

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements

```
SELECT
    MNo, X, Y, Z
FROM
    Coord C
    JOIN Result R ON R.ResultID = C.ResultID
    JOIN Member M ON M.MemberID = R.MemberID
WHERE
    M.StdID = @stdID
GROUP BY
    MNo
```

I have a query witch gives me x-, y- and z-coordinates for every Member represented by MNo. Some Members can have more than one row of coordinates, and I would like to get the mean of those coordinates (and only those), like

```
MNo     x       y       z
15      10.6    12.3    20.1
16      11.1    17.8    14.0
```

omitting Members 1-14 and 17- with only one row of coordinates. How can I do this?

Comment: Wich RDMS do you use? I think you can solve your problem with pivot tables.

Comment: What is your sample data from which you derived this output?

Comment: Mean being "usual average" would just be `AVG(X), AVG(Y), AVG(Z)` on say, MySQL.  Other DB's may vary but should have the same aggregate function possibly with a different name.

Answer (score 2):

For part 1 of your question - averaging, AVG is what you need.

For part 2 of your question - how to filter out members 1-14 and 17-, you want a WHERE clause.

For part 3 of your question - how to get rid of members with only 1 row of coordinates, you want a HAVING clause.

Bringing those together, we have:

```
SELECT
    MNo, AVG(X) AS X, AVG(Y) AS Y, AVG(Z) AS Z
FROM
    Coord C
    JOIN Result R ON R.ResultID = C.ResultID
    JOIN Member M ON M.MemberID = R.MemberID
WHERE
    M.StdID = @stdID
   AND M.MNo NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 14
   AND M.MNo NOT BETWEEN 17 and 20
GROUP BY
    MNo
HAVING
    COUNT(1) > 1
```

Notes:

- If you only called out members 1-14 and 17- because those are the members with only one set of coordinates, then you can ignore the two "AND M.MNo NOT IN" statements.
- The field in the COUNT(1) doesn't really matter (could alternatively be COUNT(*) or COUNT(X), etc. - any field will return the number of rows, and the HAVING filter will remove cases where there was only 1 row.

Comment: I believe 1-14, and 17- were simply examples of 3), so it seems 2) and 3) may be the same requirement?  Also, in such cases `COUNT(*)` (or `COUNT(1)`) is probably the least confusing since it really is rows (records) being counted.